# Convert a list of DateTime objects to string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

I have a list of Dates returning Mondays between two dates

mondays =`[datetime.date(2019, 2, 14), datetime.date(2019, 2, 21)]`

How do I format this list to %Y%m%d format?

Expecting output list to be in the below format:

`['20190214','20190221']`

is there a way?

Comment: Look at [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.datetime.strftime), e.g. `[d.strftime('%Y%m%d') for d in mondays]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the following will work

```
[date_obj.strftime('%Y%m%d') for date_obj in mondays]
```

Output

```
['20190214', '20190221']
```