# Convert datetime generator object to list of date strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of DateTime object in a generator

```
l = [datetime.date(2016, 1, 7), datetime.date(2016, 1, 14), datetime.date(2016, 1, 21), datetime.date(2016, 1, 28), datetime.date(2016, 2, 4)]
```

How can we convert that into a list of date strings format?

output :

```
['2016-01-07', '2016-01-21', '2016-01-28', '2016-03-04']
```

Comment: The `datetime` documentation shows you how to format a `datetime` value to a string of your choosing.  `apply` that to the list.  Where are you stuck with the process?

Comment: `s = [str(x) for x in l]` it is fairly trivial.

Comment: Why I run your command, I get your expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a list of DateTime objects to string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527912/convert-a-list-of-datetime-objects-to-string-in-python)

Comment: no but found the answer now. thank you for your inputs.

Comment: You have been on stack overflow for a while. You should know all the rules by now. And yes, this does answer your question.

Comment: The question is not repeated, it's different and I have added it because many beginners need such basics. If the question asked, doesn't mean that, one should compare the question with points. It might have been for everyone especially beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

```
import datetime
l = [datetime.date(2016, 1, 7), datetime.date(2016, 1, 14), datetime.date(2016, 1, 21), datetime.date(2016, 1, 28), datetime.date(2016, 2, 4)]
date_string = [d.strftime('%m-%d-%y') for d in l]
print(date_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and get the required output as follows:

```
import datetime
l = [datetime.date(2016, 1, 7), datetime.date(2016, 1, 14), datetime.date(2016, 1, 21), datetime.date(2016, 1, 28), datetime.date(2016, 2, 4)]
output = list(map(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),l))
print(output)
# ['2016-01-07', '2016-01-21', '2016-01-28', '2016-03-04']
```